# What is a Common Table Expression used for?

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

```
WITH Extracted_Sessions ( a,b ) AS 
(
   select a,b from db.tblnm
)
```

What does this SQL do? Could some one explain please?

Comment: Look up Common Table Expression or CTE.  It is an alternative name for the expression that can be used in the SELECT that follows.

Answer (score 4):

This is called a "common table expression". A SQL feature which has been introduced in SQL 99 if I'm not mistaken.

It is very similar to a derived table. Your example is equivalent to

```
select a,b
from (
  select a,b from db.tblnm
) as Extracted_Sessions
```

The main difference is that you can use a CTE more than once in a query, whereas with a derived table you need to repeat the underlying query each time, e.g:

```
WITH Extracted_Sessions ( a,b ) AS 
(
   select a,b from db.tblnm
)
select *
from Extracted_Sessions e1
  join Extracted_Sessions e2 on e1.a = e.2b
```

(Note this probably doesn't make sense, it's just to demonstrate that you can access the CTE more than once).

The Postgres manual has a nice tutorial on CTEs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Going to guess that that's a Common Table Expression : it's a construction that is a lot like a temp table :

Using the name `Extracted_Sessions` with columns `a` and `b` in place of the query `select a, b from db.tblnm` ... do stuff on `Extracted_Sessions` as though it was a real thing.

Commonly used to build recursive queries.